# CSS animation to run again after changing content with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to loop through some words and animate them in a "text type" fashion. This works fine on the first word, but once I update the content of the animated paragraph, the animation isn't present. Basically how can you trigger the CSS animation to run again once you've updated the content?

```js
var text = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
$('.css-typing').text(text[0]);
var i = 1;

myInt = setInterval(function() {
      $('.css-typing').text(text[i]);
      i++;
  },5000);
```

```css
.css-typing {
   width: 30em;
   color: #a7a37e;
   font-size: 3em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
   animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
   display: block;
   margin-left: 0;
 }
 @keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="css-typing">start</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this logic

```
     var el     = $('#test'), 
     newone = el.clone(true);                        //clone the existing 
     el.before(newone);                              //add it before the current 
     $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();   //remove the existing
```

**DEMO:**

```js
var text =["string1", "string2", "string3"];
$('.css-typing').text(text[0]);
var i = 1;
myInt = setInterval(function(){

$('#test').text(text[i]);
 
  var el     = $('#test'),
 newone = el.clone(true);
 el.before(newone);
 $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();
 
  i++;
},6000);
```

```css
.css-typing
{
    width: 30em;
    color: #a7a37e;
    font-size: 3em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


@keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }


@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test" class="css-typing"></p>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qdjro8pw/

Comment: I think that is because of the https script reference .. try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qdjro8pw/

Comment: still not seeing it I'm afraid.

Comment: which browser and version you are using ? I hope you are aware of IE9+ compatibility of css animations

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? all the text elements in the array now have the typing effect. nice Idea.

```js
$(function(){
var text = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
var i = 0;

if(i == 0) {
 $('.css-typing').text(text[0]).addClass("typeClass");
 ++i;
}else{

}
 
myInt = setInterval(function() {
 
 if(!$('.css-typing').hasClass("typeClass") && i >= 1 && i < text.length) {

  $('.css-typing').text(text[i]).toggleClass("typeClass")
  ++i;
 }
 else{
  $('.css-typing').removeClass("typeClass")

 }
 },2000);
 })
```

```css
  .css-typing {
    width: 30em;
    color: #a7a37e;
   font-size: 3em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
  /* -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
   animation: type 5s steps(50, end);*/
   display: block;
   margin-left: 0;
 }
 .typeClass{
  animation: type 5s steps(50, end);;
 }
 @keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="css-typing">start</p>
```

New css with Animation-fill-mode: forwards

```
.css-typing {
   width: 0;
   color: #a7a37e;
   font-size: 3em;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
  /* -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end);
   animation: type 5s steps(50, end);*/
   display: block;
   margin-left: 0;
 }
 .typeClass{
    -o-animation: type 5s steps(50, end) forwards;
    -webkit-animation: type 5s steps(50, end) forwards;
    animation: type 5s steps(50, end) forwards;
 }
 @keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
   to{
    width:30em;
   }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes type {
   from {
     width: 0;
   }
   to{
    width:30em;
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works on the snippet, but separated out into a browser (chrome, latest) the first animation works, then it just flashes through the rest of the array.

Comment: Maybe try putting in the prefix for the browser your using for the animation I didn't put prefixes. BTW I updated code so the first string gets animated at the beginning. and to stop animating when there are no more strings

Comment: Tried, it's weird. This snippet only works in chrome, not safari, maybe due to prefixes, but doesn't work at all in my browsers (chrome, safari) with or without prefixes. Funky business.

Comment: Can you replace the css with the new css I just added below the snippet in the answer to your text editor in the proper location and open it in the browser and see if the animation works. I added `forwards` to the animation and prefixes. It sucks that this is not multi browser compatible.Let me know if this works. Another solution is to use GSAP for web animations.EDIT and I also added width 0 in `.css-typing`